# One excellent year of Ethereum Stack Exchange - happy birthday!

Tags: discussion, statistics, self-evaluation

TL;DR **Happy Birthday Ethereum Stack Exchange Community!  Let's remind people we have a high quality library of questions and answers on Ethereum**.

[image: excellent]

<del>On January 20th 2016, or **365** days ago, [Ethereum Stack Exchange launched](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89704) with its first question:</del>

> <del>[Is Vitalik Buterin a real Satoshi Nakamoto ? [deleted]](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1)</del>

Oh, well, that didn't work out. Let's do that again. On January 20th 2016, or **365** days ago, [Ethereum Stack Exchange launched](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89704) with its *second* question:

> [How can an Ethereum contract get data from a website?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2)

Since that moment, **4269** questions and **5159** answers had been posted in the last **12** months. We now have **5256** registered users and **2902** unique visitors per day, mainly coming from search engines.

We want to take the chance to thank every user for visiting, reading, asking brilliant questions, and contributing outstanding answers. *You* helped this site to become one of the *most active* beta sites [within the whole Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) network right from the beginning.

## **Happy Birthday Ethereum Stack Exchange Community!**

[image: snapchat]

But enough self-adulation, no meta post should come without a **call-for-participation**: Please use the <del>comments and</del> answers below to **post your honest opinion** on Ethereum Stack Exchange:

- How likely is it that you would recommend Ethereum Stack Exchange to a friend or colleague? Where 0 is not likely at all and 10 is very likely.
- What's working well so far? What's working not so well?
- Are enough questions answered? And is it taking too long to receive an answer?
- Do you feel this is a dedicated, stand-alone community yet? Or is it just a subset of [r/ethereum](http://reddit.com/r/ethereum) posting technical questions here?
- Is it helping reduce the questions on Gitter and r/ethereum ?

Please continue to remind others that they can find very good answers to their questions here, and if [it hasn't been asked and isn't an opinion-based or chatty question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), to encourage them to ask here.  :)  Of course, very welcome for them to post great answers too!

Happy *new* year,

JorisBontje ♦ && eth ♦ && 5chdn ♦

Update: [65 **Yearling** badges arwarded already](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13)! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Congrats ! I'm sorry not to participate as much as before, but I'm still trying to do my best. Happy birthday to us!

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations on a great first year!

- **How likely is it that you would recommend Ethereum Stack Exchange to
  a friend or colleague? Where 0 is not likely at all and 10 is very
  likely.** 10
- **What's working well so far? What's working not so well?** Most answers are very high quality. Visitors and questions/day are excellent. Some answers while accurate at the time become outdated by later development.
- **Are enough questions answered? And is it taking too long to receive an answer?** Answer percentages and speed is excellent. The bounty system appears to work well to bring more attention to unanswered questions
- **Do you feel this is a dedicated, stand-alone community yet?** Yes
- **Is it helping reduce the questions on Gitter and r/ethereum ?** SE is clearly helping but the results may be masked by overall Ethereum community growth. The number of technical questions remain high there but those communities are also much larger than a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

For the answers,

1. 10,
2. community seems to be active, but there is more and more duplicates. Perhaps answers are hard to find after some time.
3. it's ok.
4. it's a real dedicated community with sometimes links to Reddit but here it's so much more serious and experienced answers. Also questions are better.
5. I don't know, how could we know?